# Google Form - New Row

Tags: google-forms

I already saw other questions from other users and I still couldnt help myself on this problem.

Im using google form on my job to help my team mates to simulate some jobs and im using  forms to make it easier without using the sheet in itself. Im using one page for the form and one page for the calculations based on the replies from that form.

The problem, as you know it, everytime I complete a form it makes a new row, and it doenst go to my calculation page. It jumps ahead 1 row.

Any suggestion on how I can make it block the jumping row?

Answer (score 0):

I apologise if I am not understanding your problem fully, but I think you mean you're trying to add a calculated column in Google Sheets based on responses in Google Forms?

Let's say, for example, on the form there is a question for length and a question for width and you want Sheets to automatically calculate the area by multiplying the values in the Responses sheet.

You can't drag the formula down the column because when a new response is submitted in Google Forms, Google Sheets adds it as a new row, and the formula is not included.

You've done the right thing by having a separate sheet that deals with calculations but you should use an Array Formula that will refer to the whole column of the Responses sheet, and it would need an IF statement to account for the first row, which has the headers.

I think this video explains everything better than I could:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v-hQ3EecdE

Comment: Hello Adamn, let me have some time and I will try that video, but for what a I saw in 3 minutes it was that I was talking about, Thanks for the time you had helping me.